# MVC, C# Passing parent.id to child Index or Create Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[The closest I found to my question was this but I don't understand how it would be used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834020/how-to-pass-the-id-of-the-parent-to-the-create-view-of-a-child)

```
<% object parentModel = ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData.Model; %>
```

I have a **gateway** table and a **sensor** table.  Gateways can have multiple sensors.  The tables have an association of 1 to many (gateway to sensor) and the sensor table has a gatewayid field upon which the sensor is related to a gateway.

I am using the entity framework 
I have a gateway repository class 
I have a gateway controller class 
I have a gateway partial buddy class to handle Data Annotations 
I have an index view that lists the gateways and provides the classic crud pages

On the gateway list I have added an action link to list the sensors associated with a given gateway.

All good so far (I hope).

I assume that now I should create the same setup for my sensors table; repository, controller, buddy class, etc.

**Q1:** What is the MVC approach to listing all sensors (child records) for a given gateway (parent record)?

On each gateway line item I have generated a link that looks like this:

```
localhost/sensor/list/5
```

This would indicate that the list should only display the sensors for the current gateway.

I don't think this is the right way to go.  I think I should be passing a gateway model in the background so that anytime I issue a link like this:

```
localhost/sensor/
```

it would simply understand the context of the current gateway.

**Q2:** The subsequent problem is how to do the same for the sensor create action.  I can set up the create controller and throw up a view form but how do I indicate which gateway the sensor is supposed to be associated with?

At the top of the SensorController class:

```
SensorRepository repository = new SensorRepository();
GatewayRepository Grepository = new GatewayRepository();
```

My sensor List ActionResult method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult List(int id)
{
    Gateway gateway = Grepository.GetGateway(id);

    var sensors = repository.FindGatewaySensors(id);
    return View(sensors);
}
```

My sensor Create ActionResult method looks like this (note that I'm setting the gatewayid value before passing it to the view; it is not editable in the view form):

```
// GET: /Sensor/Create
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    Sensor sensor = new Sensor();

    sensor.gatewayid = id;
    return View(sensor);

}
```

Here is the Create ActionResult post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{

    Sensor sensor = new Sensor();

    if (TryUpdateModel(sensor))
    {
        repository.Add(sensor);
        repository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("List", new { id = sensor.gatewayid });
    }
    return View(sensor);
}
```

But this just doesn't seem right.  I'll bet there's a simple approach that I'm missing.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant anymore (old question), but here are some opinions on this (and nothing more than opinions).

For Q1, I prefer to use what I imagine being "logical" URLs with MVC - i.e. from a user perspective, the URL should let them know what resource they are likely to fetch. Since you can do some semi-fancy routing, perhaps a route such as this would be clever:

/gateways/5/sensorlist

Or some variation on that theme. Of course there are a number of ways you could set the "current" gateway, as a session variable or a session cookie for instance, but what then of someone copying the URL, mailing it to his friend saying "Check out the sensors on THIS bad boy gateway!" - it wouldn't work without a reference to the gateway (doesn't have to be the ID, some people think exposing database IDs is a bad thing).

As for Q2, my common solution to this is basically to include a hidden field in the form of the create view, indicating the ID of the gateway you want to create a sensor for. It's clean and it works, and that is usually enough for me.

If you're still waiting for an answer half a year later, I hope some of this helps! :)